# Image to memory stream, based on location

Tags: c#

I have an image column in bytes in DB & location (which stores the path of the image),
if the path is empty i used image column, if the path is not empty, i  load the image to a byte array and return the image as Memory stream either from file path or direct byte image column.

```
//query
select image,filepath from tablename;
byte[]  Image = { };
if(file path is not empty)
{
 System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
 Image = Client.DownloadData("Path of the image-http://....gif");
}
else
{
Image= datareader.GetOrdinal("image"); 
}
```

How do i assign a byte image to memory stream???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MemoryStream` constructor that takes a `byte[]` instance:

```
byte[] data = // get data...
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{

}
```

If you already have an open stream, then just write the contents of the array:

```
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks, i am supposed to pick up image in the form of bytes from file location or image (byte column datatype), i have a method which returns bytes when file path is sent, all i need now is to assign bytes to memory stream based on file path's bytes or image's bytes? Any help?

Comment: Any other approach there? gurus pls. help.

Comment: Sharpeye500, please explain what else do you need - Matthew provided the (only) way to create MemoryStream out of byt array.